# Predicate logic and domain of variables

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

if x and y share the same domain, let's say non-negative integers and the predicate is:

For all of x, there exists a y such that y > x.

Is this true? Since the domain of non-negative integers is infinite and x reaches the max value of the domain I'm unsure if infinity + 1 would be correct.

Comment: "the domain of non-negative integers is infinite" Correct.

Comment: "x reaches the max value of the domain" WRONG; what is the "max value" of non-negative integers ?

Comment: There is no "infinity + 1" in integers.